Firebase dynamic routing failing with ""Invalid Dynamic Link" error" or leading to home page
I could not make Dynamic linking working in an app.
So to keep example as simple as possible, I followed Tour Of Hero example and downloaded the code.
App works locally fine as well as when deployed to firebase hosting.
So suppose my app is deployed at myproject so it works with following urls
https://myproject.web.app/
https://myproject.web.app/heroes
https://myproject.web.app/detail/13
https://myproject.web.app/dashboard

Now I generate a dynamic link suppose https://abcde.page.link/7pqr and shown below

and on desktop/web to forward

So now in web when I go to https://abcde.page.link/7pqr in firefox or chrome , it goes beautifully to https://myproject.web.app/ and shows the app.
Now I tried following all of which fails and just either takes to home page or gives "Invalid Dynamic Link" error
https://abcde.page.link/7pqr/heroes
https://abcde.page.link/7pqr?route=heroes
https://abcde.page.link/7pqr?utm_route=heroes
https://abcde.page.link/7pqr/detail/13

What wrong I am doing. I know Dynamic link will cease to exist in August 2025, but for now it should work.
